# get all levels parents from id term

Tags: hierarchical, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I have a term referenced by $id. The term is inside a tree of levels.

```
rootlevel parent (parent=0)
    first level parent
       second level parent
           ...
           ...
           last level parent
                many terms, my term $id
```

How can I get all the parents: root level, first level, second level ..., last level parent of my term?

Comment: Have you attempted anything to achieve this?

Comment: I am trying a while loop with condition parent!=0, but I guess there is a wp function to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get all of the parents of an object via [`get_ancestors`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors) -

```
$term_id = 42;
$your_taxonomy = 'sometax';
$parents = get_ancestors( $term_id, $your_taxonomy );
```